# How to put something inside new opened window using jQuery

Tags: jquery, window.open

I have 2 files. **current.htm** and **new.htm**.

I used `window.open()` in `current.htm` to open other file and specified a name to the new one.

Now, I need to put some text in a certain part of new.htm (for example a `<div>`).

How can I do it with **jQuery**?

Comment: So, you want to dynamically modify the DOM of a child window.

Comment: Thank you Shark for your editing. Yes, I have to do it just with jQuery. What I said here is just a part of my real project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you do is pull the changes across with `window.opener` as shown here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-manipulate-a-dom-in-an-window-open

*EDIT* for explanation:

in a script block in *current.htm* you could have:

```
function editChild() {
    // Do stuff with DOM here.
}
```

and in *new.htm*:

```
$(document).ready(function() {window.opener.editChild(); } );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you're right; however links are not answers so please bring an explanation into your post :)

Comment: Nice one. Good answer now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the DOM of your child window, try the below

```
$(childWindow.document).ready(function() { 
   var $theDiv = $(childWindow.document).contents().find('#yourdiv');
   // $theDiv.WhateverYouWantToDo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put `<script> ... </script>` in `new.htm` to dynamically edit the text? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Pretty sure he wants to do it from the parent.

Comment: Interpreting what I think someone is trying to do has never been my strong suit ;D

Comment: It can be difficult sometimes; this is certainly no exception!

Answer (score 0):

In new.htm: `$("div#myDiv").html("This is some text").`

Comment: Pretty sure he wants to do it from the parent.